# Changing from a White Rodgers thermostat with wire to RC to a Honeywell without RC

Tags: air-conditioning

I changed from a White Rogers thermostat to Honeywell.
The white rogers has a red wire going to RC but Honeywell doesn't have a RC.
Where do I put it?

Comment: Can you let us know all the wires you have, where they were connected, and where you plan to connect them? Maybe make a little drawing. This will get you a better answer.